# Mule(3.3.1) HTTP inbound endpoint is creating high CPU

Tags: mule, cpu, cpu-usage

Recently we start getting high CPU on our production with out making any change and with almost the same request flow to the system.

We have checked one of the method(Method: fulfilledOrder(PostBackRequest)) mentioned below but there is now any change or complicated logic that could create the issue.

## Methods consuming high CPU

Method: getLastModifiedTime(File)
Exec Sum:   938.47  CPU Sum:    712.76  Sync Sum:   0.00    Wait Sum:   0.00
Breakdown:  CPU: 75 %, Sync: 0 %, Wait: 0 %, Suspension: 0 %, I/O: 25 %
Class:  java.io.WinNTFileSystem
APIs:   Mule

Method: fulfilledOrder(PostBackRequest)
Exec Sum:   3.06    CPU Sum:    3.06    Sync Sum:   0.00    Wait Sum:   0.00
Breakdown:  CPU: 100 %, Sync: 0 %, Wait: 0 %, Suspension: 0 %, I/O: 0 %
Class:  com.mycompany.project.postback.realtime.OrderService
APIs:   mycompany

Method: execute(Runnable)
Exec Sum:   0.07    CPU Sum:    0.07    Sync Sum:   0.00    Wait Sum:   0.00
Breakdown:  CPU: 99 %, Sync: 0 %, Wait: 0 %, Suspension: 0 %, I/O: 1 %
Class:  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
APIs:   Servlet

How can I check the other two methods? Is there anything in Mule to avoid this issue? 
FYI: We are using Mule runtime version 3.3.1

Comment: The other two methods are part of Java. Just curious, what version of Java are you using?

Comment: @aled I am using Java 7

Comment: I'm sorry, but both are end of life. It might be that an update in the operating system has caused some change that the older software is not prepared to be compatible. I suggest to capture a thread dump and try to identify what is the issue. It also could something external, like an antivirus or in the platform. That Servlet mention suggest it is running in an application server like Tomcat. There could be some problem there too.